# Line feed/carriage return in svn

Tags: svn

Ok, it was my mistake. Some how I missed to uncomment the EOLStyleFromMimeTypeSetter() when migrating from cvs2svn. It is a week ago almost, and many changes has been commited, so a new migration is not an option.

What do I do now? I have manually set the property `svn_eol-style` to `native` on some projects, but only in trunk (IDEA helps me here doing it recursively). It takes a long time, and still I am missing all the branches.

Any good ideas?

The repository is placed on a linux.

Answer (score 2):

Batch modifying line endings and then committing is a bad plan as it will break every single diff that spans across that diff. A better plan would be to dump your svn repository from your conversion, redo the conversion and reimport your dump.

Make sure you make a backup of your repository first.

Find out the first subversion commit revision number after you did the conversion. Use this number where I use

```
# svnadmin dump -r<revision>:HEAD repository > repository.dump
```

redo your conversion

```
# svnadmin load repository < repository.dump
```

You may find that this invalidates people's working copies, so warn them to commit changes first before you do the conversion.

You may also want to do this on a test copy of your repository first to make sure it works.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
find * -type f | fgrep -v .svn/ | xargs -d '\n' dos2unix
```

or

```
find * -type f | fgrep -v .svn/ | xargs -d '\n' svn propset [...]
```

comes to mind.  (With probably a few more greps in between.)

Comment: This is possibly more invasive than re-indenting code. Anyone browsing the history will hate you for doing this.

Comment: It automates what he was already doing by hand.  I agree that another method may be preferable.